# Create SSL connection using certificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, nsurlconnection

I have ssl certificate (.cer) which was provided to me as file. 
I added it to bundle and want to use it communicating with server.

I used apple provided code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{
    DLog(@"didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge : %@",challenge);
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod
         isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"certificate" ofType:@"cer"];
        NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        CFDataRef myCertData = (__bridge CFDataRef)certData; 
        SecCertificateRef myCert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL,
                                                                myCertData);
        SecPolicyRef myPolicy = SecPolicyCreateBasicX509();         // 3
        SecCertificateRef certArray[1] = { myCert };
        CFArrayRef myCerts = CFArrayCreate(NULL,
                                           (void *)certArray,
                                           1,
                                           NULL);
        SecTrustRef myTrust;
        OSStatus status = SecTrustCreateWithCertificates(
                                                         myCerts,
                                                         myPolicy,
                                                         &myTrust);  // 4
        SecTrustResultType trustResult = 0;
        if (status == noErr) {
            status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);       // 5
        }
        // If the trust result is kSecTrustResultInvalid, kSecTrustResultDeny, kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure, you cannot proceed and should fail gracefully.
        BOOL proceed = NO;
        switch (trustResult) {
            case kSecTrustResultProceed: // 1
                DLog(@"Proceed");
                proceed = YES;
                break;
            case kSecTrustResultConfirm: // 2
                DLog(@"Confirm");
                proceed = YES;
                break;
            case kSecTrustResultUnspecified: // 4
                DLog(@"Unspecified");
                break;
            case kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure:  // 5
                DLog(@"TrustFailure");
                proceed = [self recoverFromTrustFailure:myTrust];
                break;
            case kSecTrustResultDeny: // 3
                DLog(@"Deny");
                break;
            case kSecTrustResultFatalTrustFailure: // 6
                DLog(@"FatalTrustFailure");
                break;
            case kSecTrustResultOtherError: // 7
                DLog(@"OtherError");
                break;
            case kSecTrustResultInvalid: // 0
                DLog(@"Invalid");
                break;
            default:
                DLog(@"Default");
                break;
        }
        if (myPolicy)
            CFRelease(myPolicy);
        if (proceed) {
            [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];
        }else{
            [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        }
    }
}

- (BOOL) recoverFromTrustFailure:(SecTrustRef) myTrust
{
    SecTrustResultType trustResult;
    OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);  // 1
    //Get time used to verify trust
    CFAbsoluteTime trustTime,currentTime,timeIncrement,newTime;
    CFDateRef newDate;
    if (trustResult == kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure) {// 2
        trustTime = SecTrustGetVerifyTime(myTrust);             // 3
        timeIncrement = 31536000;                               // 4
        currentTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent();               // 5
        newTime = currentTime - timeIncrement;                  // 6
        if (trustTime - newTime){                               // 7
            newDate = CFDateCreate(NULL, newTime);              // 8
            SecTrustSetVerifyDate(myTrust, newDate);            // 9
            status = SecTrustEvaluate(myTrust, &trustResult);   // 10
        }
    }
    if (trustResult != kSecTrustResultProceed) {
        DLog(@"Failed with status : %li",trustResult);               // 11
        return NO;
    }else{
        DLog(@"Procced");
        return YES;
    }
}
```

However i am getting **kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure** . Also used apple sample in this situation but it didn't helped.

Maybe some one could help me on this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Is the certificate meant to be for your client, or is it the server certificate that you are supposed to trust?

Comment: I should trust this certificate. Actually i don't have experience in this kind of work so i could speak nonsense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If this is a self signed certificate to be used in server trust authentication, you should do the following:

1. Convert the .CRT encoded certificate into a .DER encoded certificate. On the terminal type:

   `$: openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -outform der -out "com.server.trust_cert.der"`

   (choose your own meaningful name)

   Put the .DER encoded certificate into the bundle.
2. Implement the method `connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:` as follows. 
   Important: always check for errors and bail out and let the authentication fail if *anything* is wrong!!

   Test it thoroughly!

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    if ([[[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod] isEqualToString: NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
    {
        do
        {
            SecTrustRef serverTrust = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
            if (serverTrust == nil)
                break; // failed

            SecTrustResultType trustResult;
            OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &trustResult);
            if (!(errSecSuccess == status))
                break; // fatal error in trust evaluation -> failed

            if (!((trustResult == kSecTrustResultProceed) 
               || (trustResult == kSecTrustResultUnspecified)))
            {
                break; // see "Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference" 
                       // for explanation of result codes.
            }

            SecCertificateRef serverCertificate = SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex(serverTrust, 0);
            if (serverCertificate == nil)
                break; // failed

            CFDataRef serverCertificateData = SecCertificateCopyData(serverCertificate);
            if (serverCertificateData == nil)
                break; // failed

            const UInt8* const data = CFDataGetBytePtr(serverCertificateData);
            const CFIndex size = CFDataGetLength(serverCertificateData);
            NSData* server_cert = [NSData dataWithBytes:data length:(NSUInteger)size];
            CFRelease(serverCertificateData);

            NSString* file = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"com.server.trust_cert"
                                                             ofType:@"der"];
            NSData* my_cert = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file];

            if (server_cert == nil || my_cert == nil)
                break; // failed

            const BOOL equal = [server_cert isEqualToData:my_cert];
            if (!equal)
                break; // failed 

            // Athentication succeeded:
            return [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:serverTrust]
                          forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
        } while (0);

        // Authentication failed: 
        return [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    }
}
```

#### Note:

A possible improvement of the above technique is to use "public key pinning".

#### Must Reads:

[HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) (Official Apple Documentation, Technical Note TN2232)

[Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html) (Official Apple Reference Documentation)

Comment: But here is compared file size (bytes). So if some server have file which is same size as cert in app than it will be trusted ? I found more info here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html

Comment: No. `[server_cert isEqualToData:my_cert]` evaluates to `YES` only if the two byte sequences are equal. It's a comparison byte by byte. The length must be the same, too. You may find this useful: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning

Comment: Here is a thread on the Apple developer forum (requires account) that specifically address your issue:  https://devforums.apple.com/message/737087#737087  Quinn gives an exact answer here:https://devforums.apple.com/message/738170#738170