# iOS HTTPS requests 101

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, ssl, https

```
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)
```

Very, very frustrating! I've been pulling my hair for hours with this. I'm using a self-signed certificate on my Linode server. The port is 8000, couldn't get it to work on 443. I don't believe this is the reason though. Here's my code, it's 99% boilerplate:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.myserver.com:8000/test.json"]];
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

At the bottom:

```
#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDelegate

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    NSLog(@"protectionSpace: %@", [protectionSpace authenticationMethod]);

    // We only know how to handle NTLM authentication.
    if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodNTLM])
        return YES;

    // Explicitly reject ServerTrust. This is occasionally sent by IIS.
    if([[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        return NO;

    return NO;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [[challenge sender] continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"%@", response);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    NSLog(@"%@", data);
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]]);
}
```

OMG HELP!

**UPDATE**

It worked with this delegate method. I'm receiving the response, but there is a problem.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:[NSURLCredential
                                       credentialWithUser:@"user"
                                       password:@"password"
                                       persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

}
```

The "user" and "password" that I have provided are completely random and aren't checked by the server. **How can I verify the credentials before accepting the connection on my server?**

EDIT: I'm running a Node.js server

Comment: "The "user" and "password" that I have provided are completely random and aren't checked by the server" - that's a different question. You should ask it as a separate question and perhaps link back to this question. Linode configuration may be off-topic, so you may have to wander over to Super User or Server Fault. (And you should probably accept Fonix answer since it appears to have helped you resolve the issue).

Answer (score 8):

Getting the corresponding error description may help:

So, first the error domain `kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL` means that the error code is an SSL error code as defined in Security/SecureTransport.h:

kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813 means:

`errSSLNoRootCert = -9813,  /* cert chain not verified by root */`

And that simply means, you have no trusted root certificate and the connection fails because of that authentication failure.

Provide a root certificate on the device for the *server trust authentication* and you are fine.

There are a few approaches to implement server trust authentication with self-signed certificates, the one more secure than the other.

The simplest approach requires a self-signed certificate which is stored in the bundle of the app, then retrieved and simply byte-compared. Here is an example:

[Implementing server trust authentication with a self-signed certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17141226/create-ssl-connection-using-certificate/17146532#17146532).

These are a must read also:  [Technical Note TN2232
HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2232/_index.html) and [Technical Q&A QA1360 Describing the kSecTrustResultUnspecified error](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1360/_index.html).

The more preferred approach is to use a CA (Certificate Authority) which you can be yourself. That is, you create your own CA and your certificates signed with this CA.

The steps are similar:

1. Bundel the DER file of your CA's root certificate in your app.
2. Handle the server trust authentication as follows:

   1. get the authentication challenge
   2. retrieve the trust object from the challenge
   3. create a certificate object from the data in your bundle
   4. set the certificate object as an anchor to the trust object using function `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates`.
   5. evaluate the trust

Comment: Here is the URL for decrypting other error codes ... http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-36800/lib/SecureTransport.h

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this will actually fix the problem, but it may help. you should be using

```
– connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:
```

since the other methods are deprecated. take a look at the overview of the [NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: unfortunately im a bit of a noob with this authentication stuff, so im not sure