# SecTrustEvaluate NOT failing as expected?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, ssl

I've got some code that performs an HTTPS fetch on `example.com`.

The problem is, I'm plugging in a fake CA below (`@"ca-rsa-cert.der"`), so `SecTrustEvaluate` should fail. (Or I got lucky and generated the same public/private key pair as the real example.com's signing certifcate).

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:
(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    do
    {
        SecTrustRef serverTrust = [[challenge protectionSpace] serverTrust];
        if(nil == serverTrust)
            break; /* failed */

        NSData* caCert = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"ca-rsa-cert.der"];
        if(nil == caCert)
            break; /* failed */

        SecCertificateRef caRef = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)caCert);
        if(nil == caRef)
            break; /* failed */

        NSArray* caArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(__bridge id)(caRef)];
        if(nil == caArray)
            break; /* failed */

        OSStatus status = SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates(serverTrust, (__bridge CFArrayRef)caArray);
        if(!(errSecSuccess == status))
            break; /* failed */

        status = SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, NULL);
        if(!(errSecSuccess == status))
            break; /* failed */

        // The only good exit point
        return [[challenge sender] useCredential: [NSURLCredential credentialForTrust: serverTrust]
                      forAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];

    } while(0);

    // Bad dog
    return [[challenge sender] cancelAuthenticationChallenge: challenge];
}
```

Essentially, the steps are the same as outlined at [iOS HTTPS requests 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033525/ios-https-requests-101) (the question is about loading a CA certificate). I've also reviewed Apple TN2232 [HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) and [Overriding TLS Chain Validation Correctly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/NetworkingTopics/Articles/OverridingSSLChainValidationCorrectly.html), but I don't see my mistake.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I should have paid more attention to the details in [TN2232 HTTPS Server Trust Evaluation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2232/_index.html) and [QA1360 Describing the kSecTrustResultUnspecified error](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1360/_index.html).

```
status = SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, NULL);
if(!(errSecSuccess == status))
    break; /* failed */
```

I was not using the API correctly. The `OSStatus` only provides if the call to `SecTrustEvaluate` succeeded (or failed). To get the result of the evaluation:

```
SecTrustResultType result
status = SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &result);
if(!(errSecSuccess == status))
    break; /* failed */

if(result != kSecTrustResultUnspecified && result != kSecTrustResultProceed)
    break; /* failed */

...
```