# iOS / iPhone - Using SIOSocket with SSL to connect to socket.io server

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, websocket, socket.io

I have a socket.io server to which I connect my iOS app using SIOSocket. I connect using websockets

Everything works fine if I connect to an unsecured TCP connection on port 80 but if I try to connect via SSL to port 443, SIOSocket fails to connect with this error:

```
NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9843)
```

Does SIOSocket support SSL and if so am I doing something wrong ? 
Or is it the case that SIOSocket simply doesn't support SSL?

I undertsand from [This stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033525/ios-https-requests-101) that the problem could be a root certificate issue but my SSL certificate is from an official CA..

thanks.