# Unable to use self signed certificate with AFNetworking 2

Tags: ios, apache, ssl-certificate, afnetworking-2

I put the .cer certificate used by the Apache Server in the Xcode project. When the app tries to talk to the server I get this error in Xcode:

```
Assertion failure in id AFPublicKeyForCertificate(NSData *__strong)(),
/Users/../ProjectName/AFNetworking/AFSecurityPolicy.m:52
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', 
reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: allowedCertificate'
```

Here is the code for calling the server :

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
[self setSecurityPolicy:[AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey]];
[manager POST:@"https://www.example.com/" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
//success
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
//failure
}];
```

I changed the pinning mode to AFSSLPinningModeCertificate with no luck.

and when I remove this line:

```
[self setSecurityPolicy:[AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModePublicKey]];
```

the server responds with the error message:

```
"The operation couldn't be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"
```

The certificate was created using OpenSSL, and I even tried a free certificate from StartSSL.com

As for the Apache Server side, here is the virtual host configuration:

```
# My custom host
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/folder"
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/www.example.com.cer
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/www.example.com.key
    <Directory "/the/directory/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/mysite.local-error_log"
</VirtualHost>
```

and the server does listen to the 443 port

Answer (score 9):

It looks like your certificate file is not in the right format. Your code fails at these lines (`AFURLConnectionOperation/pinnedPublicKeys`):

```
SecCertificateRef allowedCertificate = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef)data);
NSParameterAssert(allowedCertificate);
```

I had the same error (on `AFNetworking 1.1`, but the version should not matter), when my certificate was looking like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
..
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I managed to resolve this by converting the certificate to x509 format, using the command from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17146532/727817):

```
openssl x509 -in adn.crt -outform der -out "adn.der"
```

Afterwards I renamed `adn.der` back to `adn.cer` ('.cer' seems to be the expected extension for `AFNetworking`), and everything works well now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't on the side of AFNetworkings, but on iOS': You need to install the self-signed certificate on the device, because the iOS security settings forbid connections to untrusted sources.

You can add a self-signed certificate as a trusted source by opening the certificate on you iOS device (mail it to yourself and open it) and following the install instructions.

Comment: That's what I'am suspecting, because I've been using the iOS simulator

Answer (score 0):

If required, you can disable the invalid certificate check by changing your security policy.

```
[self setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
```

Please read more in the documentation: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/Classes/AFSecurityPolicy.html#//api/name/allowInvalidCertificates

You can also pin the certificate: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.3/Classes/AFSecurityPolicy.html#//api/name/pinnedCertificates

Comment: would this work on the iOS simulator?
because I still get the error on AFSecurityPolicy.m:52 with this : 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: allowedCertificate'

Answer (score 0):

This site may help someone fix this http://www.indelible.org/ink/trusted-ssl-certificates/

Example

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/1.x

Comment: Could you post some content from your links?