# allow invalid certificates with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking-2

I have been using following code

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
operation.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate=YES;
```

Now i have changed AFNetworking to latest version that is 2.0. **operation.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate** is not working anymore with **AFHTTPRequestOperation**. As per documents i used

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

and my request code is

```
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSLog (@"success: %@", operation.responseString);

}
                                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                      NSLog(@"error: %@",  error.description);
                                  }
 ];

[operation start];
[operation waitUntilFinished];
```

But this is not working for HTTPS which require certificates. What should i do to make this work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding following code before **[operation start];**

```
AFSecurityPolicy *sec=[[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
[sec setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
operation.securityPolicy=sec;
```

This happened because **AFHTTPRequestOperationManager** is not connected to **AFHTTPRequestOperation**. So setting manager's security certificate can not do magic at requestOperation. So have to initialize and assign one to **AFHTTPRequestOperation**.

Hope this help somebody :)

Comment: I confirm that this is the solution. However I would have liked a more explicit error message from AFNetworking instead of "canceled" that does not mean much.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. It's an iOS 7 issue. Apple does not allow communication with self signed certificate websites. Unless you send the certificate to device and add as a trusted certificate list.

Supporting comment on other question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20251011/753603

Couldn't find piece of documented text by Apple.

Comment: If i use 1.x version of AFNetworking it is working in ios7 with invalidCertificate

Comment: Ohh interesting, then could you please try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/20251854/753603