# AFNetworking 2.2 SSL pinning with self-signed certificate

Tags: ios, ssl, nginx, openssl, afnetworking-2

I want to prevent my app/server communication from a MITM attack so I am trying to setup SSL pinning, but I am having problems getting it working with AFNetworking 2.2, using a self-signed certificate. I think it's mostly a problem with how I am generating the certificate.

I first tried generating a self-signed certificate according to [these instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-12-04):

Generating the private key:

```
sudo openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 2048
```

Generating the Signing Request, and using the domain name when asked for the Common Name:

```
sudo openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
```

Generating the certificate:

```
sudo openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Finally, converting it to `der` format (since AFNetworking [requires it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20227700/unable-to-use-self-signed-certificate-with-afnetworking-2))

```
sudo openssl x509 -outform der -in server.crt -out server.der
```

The server is Ubuntu 12.04, running ngninx+passenger to serve up a Rails 4 app.  Here is the bit of my nginx server config to turn on SSL:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443;
  server_name myapp.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /var/www/myapp/current/public;
  rails_env production;
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
}
```

After restarting nginx, downloading the `der` file, adding it to my project, and renaming it "server.cer" (since AFNetworking requires the certificate to use the .cer extension), I use this code to turn on SSL pinning for my `AFHTTPSessionManager` subclass:

```
client.securityPolicy = [AFSecurityPolicy 
                          policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
```

Then, with the first request to the server AFNetworking attempts to verify that the "trust is valid in the `AFServerTrustIsValid` function:

```
static BOOL AFServerTrustIsValid(SecTrustRef serverTrust) {
    SecTrustResultType result = 0;

    OSStatus status = SecTrustEvaluate(serverTrust, &result);
    NSCAssert(status == errSecSuccess, @"SecTrustEvaluate error: %ld", (long int)status);

    return (result == kSecTrustResultUnspecified || result == kSecTrustResultProceed);
}
```

If I put a breakpoint at the return, I can see that the result is always `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure`.

If I skip the `AFServerTrustIsValid` function by setting `allowInvalidCertificates` to `YES` on the security policy, then the request succeeds. But I don't really want to allow invalid certificates if I don't have to.

Back to the drawing board, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715426/what-is-the-reason-of-ksectrustresultrecoverabletrustfailure) lead me to [this tutorial](http://linuxconfig.org/apache-web-server-ssl-authentication) on creating a self-signed cert with also creating a CA.  I setup my openssl.cnf file like so:

```
[ req ]
default_md = sha1
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName = United Kingdon
countryName_default = UK
countryName_min = 2
countryName_max = 2
localityName = Locality
localityName_default = London
organizationName = Organization
organizationName_default = Eric Organization
commonName = Common Name
commonName_max = 64

[ certauth ]
subjectKeyIdentifier = hash
authorityKeyIdentifier = keyid:always,issuer:always
basicConstraints = CA:true
crlDistributionPoints = @crl

[ server ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
nsCertType = server
subjectAltName = DNS:myapp.com
crlDistributionPoints = @crl

[ crl ]
URI=http://testca.local/ca.crl
```

And then used these commands to generate everything. First the CA stuff:

```
sudo openssl req -config ./openssl.cnf -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyform PEM -keyout ca.key -x509 -days 3650 -extensions certauth -outform PEM -out ca.cer
```

Then again the server's private key:

```
sudo openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
```

The signing request:

```
sudo openssl req -config ./openssl.cnf -new -key server.key -out server.req
```

The certificate:

```
sudo openssl x509 -req -in server.req -CA ca.cer -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 100 -extfile openssl.cnf -extensions server -days 365 -outform PEM -out server.cer
```

And finally the `der` file:

```
sudo openssl x509 -outform der -in server.cer -out stopcastapp.com.der
```

When I update and restart nginx,, download and add the `server.der` to my project (making sure to rename it to `server.cer` and to reset the Simulator), I get the same exact result.

The dreaded `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure` rears its ugly head again.

What am I doing wrong?  Am I like WAY off on how this all works, or do I need to tweak just one little thing to get it all working? If you could help in any way I would really, really appreciate it (I've been on this problem for two days now).  Thanks!

Comment: For now I got this to work using Keychain Assistant on Mac OS X and by overriding how AFNetworking 2.2 does pinning for self-signed certificates. [I wrote about it here](http://initwithfunk.com/blog/2014/03/12/afnetworking-ssl-pinning-with-self-signed-certificates/). Note that certificate pinning in AFNetworking for self-signed certs is going to be fixed pretty soon. I'll update this post when it does.

Comment: is it Afnetworking issue? Any luck?

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score -2):

Somewhere in your code you need to specify this, or something similar. You need to tell the code to accept invalid certificates (AKA self signed).

```
self.allowsInvalidSSLCertificate = YES;
```